# Problem on front end shipping table rate calculation amount not showing correctly in review order page - magento2.3

Tags: checkout, magento2.3, orders

*I am using magento2.3*

```
table rate -> enabled:yes

condition:Weight vs Destination

Ship to Applicable Countries:specific countries

Include Virtual Products in Price Calculation:yes

Calculate Handling Fee:Fixed, Ship to Specific Countries: India
```

*the Table rate Select Shipping Method page showing the table rate amount correct but it not showing correctly in Review order page*

[image: In this image1(click on link) table rate amount showing correctly(Address 1 of 3)]

[image: In this image2(click on link) the table rate amount not showing correctly(Address 1 of 3)]

[image: Address 2 of 3 image3 link]

[image: Address 3 0f 3 image4 link]

In this image1(click on image) table rate amount showing correctly(Address 1 of 3)

In this image2(click on image) the table rate amount not showing correctly(Address 1 of 3), But total value of Address 1 of 3 is correct but showing value is not correct

Address 2 of 3 image3 image

Address 3 0f 3 image4 image

Single Address delivery it's working fine,This issue will happen in multi address delivery time only.***

*How to fix this issue,Please help me....*